# Non linear optimization wrt to square matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus, numerical-optimization

Given vectors $\pmb{y}_0, \pmb{y}_1, \dots \pmb{y}_t \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $F : \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}_0^+$ be defined by

$$F(W) := \left\| \pmb{y}_1 - W \pmb{y}_0 \right\|^2 + \left\| \pmb{y}_2 - W^2 \pmb{y}_0 \right\|^2 + \cdots + \left\| \pmb{y}_t - W^t \pmb{y}_0 \right\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{t} \left\| \pmb{y}_i - W^i \pmb{y}_0 \right\|^2 $$

I need to (numerically) minimize the function $F$. I tried calculating the gradient $\nabla_W F$, but the gradient of (almost) arbitrary matrix to a power seems to be hard to calculate. I would much appreciate if you showed me, how to calculate $\nabla_W F$, or if you came up with another solution to this problem.

Comment: What has $v$ got to do with it all?

Comment: I just showed what I mean by the square of a vector

Comment: A more usual notation would be $\|v\|^2$. The derivative of a power is not hard to compute, it is just ugly, it is $D (W^t)H = A^{t-1}H + A^{t-2}HA+...+H A^{t-1}$.

Comment: Thank you, I will edit the question.

Comment: My comment has a typo, $A$ should be $W$.

Comment: Which vector norm? Euclidean?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes, totally. Makes the question more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\def\a{\phi}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\op{Sym}\LR{#1}}
\def\skew#1{\op{Skew}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\Sj{\sum_{j=\o}^k\:}
$Calculate the differential of the $k^{th}$ power of the matrix
$$\eqalign{
dW^k &= \Sj W^{j-\o}\:dW\:W^{k-j} \\
}$$
Then calculate the gradient of the $k^{th}$ term of the sum
$$\eqalign{
z_k &\equiv \LR{W^ky_0-y_k} \qquad \{{\rm for\;convenience}\} \\
\a_k &= \frob{z_k}^2 \\
d\a_k &= 2z_k:dz_k \\
 &= 2z_k:\LR{dW^k\;y_o} \\
 &= 2z_ky_0^T:\c{dW^k} \\
 &= 2\LR{y_0z_k^T}^T:\LR{\Sj W^{j-\o}\:dW\:W^{k-j}} \\
 &= 2\LR{\Sj W^{j-\o}\:y_0\c{z_k^T}W^{k-j}}^T:dW \\
 &= 2\LR{\Sj W^{j-\o}\:y_0\CLR{W^ky_0-y_k}^\c{T}W^{k-j}}^T:dW \\
\grad{\a_k}{W}
 &= 2\LR{\Sj W^{j-\o}\:y_0\LR{W^ky_0-y_k}^TW^{k-j}}^T \\
}$$
where a colon denotes the matrix inner product, which has these properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{AB}:C &= A:\LR{CB^T} \;=\; B:\LR{A^TC} \\
\\
}$$

Summing over all terms recovers your function
$$\eqalign{
F &= \sum_{k=\o}^{\large t} \a_k \qiq
\grad FW &= \sum_{k=\o}^{\large t} \grad{\a_k}{W} \\
}$$